# Вывод постов в WordPress по произвольному полю

Tags: php, wordpress

День добрый.

Задача - сделать простую афишу на WordPress.

Я создал произвольное поле **"event_date"**, в котором указываю дату проведения мероприятия в виде **20150125** (25 января 2015).

Сейчас посты выводятся следующим образом: 25 января (ПОСЛЕЗАВТРА), 24 января (ЗАВТРА), 23 января (СЕГОДНЯ), 22 января, 21 января.

**Код в index.php:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if(is_category($afisha)) {
query_posts('cat=2&order=desc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=event_date'.'&paged='.$paged);
}
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<section id="content">
<article>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php do_excerpt(get_the_excerpt(),15); ?>
</article>
</section>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Вопрос:** как сделать, чтобы посты выводились в таком виде: 23 января (СЕГОДНЯ), 24 января (ЗАВТРА), 25 января (ПОСЛЕЗАВТРА), а потом те события, которые уже завершились - 22 января, 21 января?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что-то похожее делал, можно двумя запросами сделать, сначала вывести все новые с `order=>DESC`, а потом вывести все пердшествующие этому дню с `order=>ASC`, и, по-моему, надо не забыть потом сбросить `query_posts`:

```
    $argss = array(  
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'meta_key' => 'technicaltime',
            'posts_per_page' => 2, //10
            'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'orderby' => 'meta_value',
         'cat' => $idcat,
        'meta_query' => array(  
                array(  
                    'key' => 'technicaltime',  
                    'value' => array( (int)$fromdate, (int)$todate ),
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN' 
                ))
        );
        query_posts( $argss );
         if (have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'content-calendar', get_post_format() );
         endwhile;
         endif;

wp_reset_query();
```